# Show multiple images in a view

Tags: android, imageview

```
package com.test.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class helloworld extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
    i.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name);
    setContentView(i);        
    }
}
```

This is a simple app that shows a specific image (image_name) from the res/drawable folder.

Since i can't use `setContentView()` multiple times, how can i show multiple images in the same view? (all images are saved in the drawable folder)

Comment: use listview or grid view to add multiple images

Comment: Yussuf, you mentioned you want to have multiple images in the same view. Instead of that you can try with [ListView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)

Comment: You can overlay multiple ImageViews at the same location by using a Relative Layout. OR you can overlay multiple images in a single bitmap by code.

Comment: `setContentView()` sets the view for the whole activity. You should use a layout from the layout folder resources for that method. In the layout add views to show your images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create multiple image view and use grid layout.

if you want to display full size image that should be changed on swipe or button click then try using fragments and a frame layout.